# Basic Architectural issue for developing a ticketing system

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to make a ticketing system, am working on the architecture of application, lets keep it very simple. i have to put a textbox in which Available ticket number will be shown, and under that few moew textboxes, for general information, and then buy button.
Note: Ticket numbers must be displayed on the screen, as they have been mapped with seat numbers.
Now the issues where i am stucked are

1. if i have 50 tickets available, and a user opens the website he sees ticket # 1 available, another user opens the site and he also sees ticket # 1 available, as the first user havent bought that ticket yet. now definitely the first one who press buy button, he will be assigned with that ticket.
2. If i implement some locking mechanism, that if one user has access to a ticket, then that must not be displayed to another user. but what if the user who has opened the ticket to purchase, is not purchasing it for any reason, and even is not closing the page or not pressing the cancel button. means that ticket will be reserved until the user do some action, or i may refresh the page automatically after few mins, but still for those few mins the ticket will be reserved.

Need some approriate solution for this, so that i may start implementing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about using [ostrich algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrich_algorithm). One user will get the error "already sold".

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you have some kind of design you've made that you'd like us to review? Any specific problems with something you've tried?

Comment: Why build this, when it's really just a shopping cart, and there are many many free shopping cart solutions you could use that will do a better than job than you could on your own?

Comment: Definitely not option 2 - it is way too complex. Rather, you should be more 'optimistic', and later present an error to the user who has selected an already reserved ticket.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes thats a shopping cart, but the problem which i have listed, it will still occur in any third party shopping cart solution.

Comment: @QasimJavaidKhan accept answers and get +2! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer method #2. I've seen implementations of the problem with train seat reservation mechanisms.

Lock the ticket, and remember the lock in the Session. Then automatically unlock the locked ticket when the session expires. Configure the session to last only a minute.

Comment: With all respect to @aquaraga, I don't see this to be "way too complex". Why?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution that i can think is using with the help windows service . When the user who ever book click the book to ticket , it will be updated in the database with datetime and user identification number . In the client side you can put the javascript time to refresh  after 10 minutes or whatever . At the same time Windows service running in the background will check for all the booked time still in the pending status with more than X time and will update the item to expire . You client side for the another user will pingg the database and check if the seat is available again and you can show the user seat is available . Now in case first user try to book the ticket , your server side will again the verify the status from database and give the message that ticket need to be selected again. You can just give the optimal time that user need to process the ticket like filling the form etc...